# Simple Python Issue with Iteration and Lambda

Tags: python

```
lst = [1, 2, 3]

i = 0
f = lambda x: x * lst[i]

i = 1
print(f(10))
f = lambda x: x * lst[i]

i = 2
print(f(10))
f = lambda x: x * lst[i]
```

Above is my Python code and I thought it would print out `10, 20`, but it says `20, 30`. I don't understand why `f` is modified by `i` regardless of the explicit assignment. I've got to make it print `10, 20` using an iteration(actually the code is a simplified form of the original one), so it seems that `f = lambda x: x * 1` is not allowed.

Comment: Why do you expecting it to print `10 20`? `lst[1]` is 2 and `lst[2]` is 3, so it will print `20 30`.

Comment: Pay attention on `lst[i]` . You set `i=0` but didn't printed it out. In first case `i=0` which means `10*1`

Comment: The `lambda` doesn't capture the value of `i` at the moment it is created. The value of `i` will be evaluated at the moment you call `f`. Just as with regular `def` functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i` is global variable. so when you call `f` it uses the current value of `i`

look at

```
f = lambda x: x * lst[i]
lst = [1, 2, 3]
for i in range(len(lst)):
    print(f(10))
```

output

```
10
20
30
```

Note, not related to your question, but `f = lambda x: x * lst[i]` is against [PEP8 recommendations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id51):

> Always use a `def` statement instead of an assignment statement that
> binds a lambda expression directly to an identifier:
>
> Correct: `def f(x): return 2*x`
>
> Wrong:   `f = lambda x: 2*x`
>
> The first form means that the name of the resulting function object is
> specifically 'f' instead of the generic ''. This is more
> useful for tracebacks and string representations in general. The use
> of the assignment statement eliminates the sole benefit a lambda
> expression can offer over an explicit def statement (i.e. that it can
> be embedded inside a larger expression)

Answer (score 3):

I think you're expecting `f = lambda x: x * lst[i]` to store value of `i`, but it doesn't work that way. When a function is defined, it is just stored to be used later, it is not evaluated when it is defined. It is evaluated only when it is called.

So, when you call `f(10)` for the first time, you're passing value of `x` as 10 and the interpreter looks up for the value of `i` in memory, which is `1` during first function call and `2` during second function call. That's why you get `20 30` as output.

Feel free to ask any question if you still have doubts.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine lambda expression as a truly function, so you will get these code:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3]

i = 0
def f(x):
    return x * lst[i]

i = 1
print(f(10))  # currently x=10 and i=1
def f(x):
    return x * lst[i]

i = 2
print(f(10))  # currently x=10 and i=2
def f(x):
    return x * lst[i]
```

I know what you mean. In your head, while you define `lambda x: x * lst[i]`, you think number `i` will be frozen at this time --- just like assignment. When it be called later, the number `i` will always be the first value. It's not True. The value of `i` will be referenced when you call this function.